# Why is trigger('click') the same as $('#test').trigger({ type : 'click' });?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and basically I am trying to delve more into JS events and understand events and objects better.

I wanted to know whether `trigger('click')` is the same as `trigger({type : 'click'})`.

Now I wrote the below function to understand the difference and confirm if they are both the same:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var call_it = function() {          
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#test').trigger({
                    type : 'click' 
                });
            } , 1500 );
        }

        call_it();

        $('#test').on('click' , function(){
                console.log('button clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hekha1xh/)

now when you replace :

```
$('#test').trigger({
        type : 'click' 
    });
```

with:

```
$('#test').trigger('click' );
```

the click is still triggered, but I am still confused, **how** and **why** are they the same ?? **How** are they internally the same?

I know its a trick question.

Comment: If your interested in the nitty gritty how you can always browse the unminified source file.

Comment: @Taplar , I wish i had such JS skills to do that :D and ur right , thats exactly what i am interested in , but no as of now i am not in a position to do so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're nearly the same, yes.

When provided an `eventType`, such as `"click"`, [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) creates a [`jQuery.Event()` instance](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) from it:

```
console.log(jQuery.Event('click'));
// { type: 'click', timestamp: 14..., ... }
```

> [From the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/event.js#L246-L249) (v2.1.4):
>
> ```
> trigger: function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ) {
>       // ...
>
>       // Caller can pass in a jQuery.Event object, Object, or just an event type string
>       event = event[ jQuery.expando ] ?
>           event :
>           new jQuery.Event( type, typeof event === "object" && event );
>
>       // ..
> }
> ```

`.trigger()` also accepts such `event` objects directly:

```
$().trigger(jQuery.Event('click'))
```

And, the differences between `jQuery.Event('click')` and `{ type: 'click' }` are just the additional properties, like `timestamp`, which [aren't required by `.trigger()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/event.js#L223).

```
var i, // ...
    // ...
    type = hasOwn.call( event, "type" ) ? event.type : event,
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

They both are Same.

```
$('#test').trigger({
    type : 'click' 
});
```

This is an *Alternative way to pass data through an event object*. You can pass arbitrary data to the event through this method.

```
$('#test').trigger({
    type : 'click',
    param1 : "foo",
    param2 : "bar" 
});
```

**[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hekha1xh/3/)**

```
$("#test").click(function (event) {
    console.log(event.a)
    console.log(event.b)
    console.log(event.type)
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#test").trigger({
        type: "click",
        a: "foo",
        b: "bar"
    });
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Thaks for ur answer :D